# Code breaks when anchors overlap KineticJS

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

Code breaks when anchors overlap. I have anchors for resizing draggable groups of shapes as given in below tutorial. I also have the functionality to delete the selected group. The delete functionality breaks the code when anchors (of two different groups) overlap and overlapping anchor is selected (mousedown).

```
       if (layer !== null && e.keyCode == 46) {  //Delete Key = 46
                SelectedShape.remove();
                layer.batchDraw();
            }
        });

        //Selecting on mousedown
        layer.on('mousedown', function (evt) {
            SelectedShape = evt.targetNode.getParent();
        });
```

> Error message: Cannot get parent of a null or undefined reference.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/

Sample code

```
    var SelectedShape = null;

    function update(activeAnchor) {
    var group = activeAnchor.getParent();
    var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
    var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
        var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
        var rect = group.get('.rect')[0];

        var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
            case 'topLeft':
                topRight.setY(anchorY);
                bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'topRight':
                topLeft.setY(anchorY);
                bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'bottomRight':
                bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
                topRight.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'bottomLeft':
                bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
                topLeft.setX(anchorX);
                break;
        }

        rect.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition());

        var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
        var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        if (width && height) {
            rect.setSize(width, height);
        }
    }
    function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var stage = group.getStage();
        var layer = group.getLayer();

        var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            stroke: '#666',
            fill: '#ddd',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            radius: 8,
            name: name,
            draggable: true,
            dragOnTop: false
        });

        anchor.on('dragmove', function () {
            update(this);
            layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function () {
            group.setDraggable(false);
            this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on('dragend', function () {
            group.setDraggable(true);
            layer.draw();
        });
        group.add(anchor);
    }

        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 578,
            height: 400
        });
        var darthVaderGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
            x: 270,
            y: 100,
            draggable: true
        });
        var yodaGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
            x: 100,
            y: 110,
            draggable: true
        });

        var Group3 = new Kinetic.Group({
            x: 100,
            y: 300,
            draggable: true
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        /* add the groups to the layer and the layer to the stage*/
        layer.add(darthVaderGroup);
        layer.add(yodaGroup);
        layer.add(Group3);
        stage.add(layer);

        // darth vader
        var darthVaderImg = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 200,
            height: 138,
            fill: 'green',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 4,
            name: 'rect'
        });

        darthVaderGroup.add(darthVaderImg);
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 0, 'topRight');
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 200, 138, 'bottomRight');
        addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 138, 'bottomLeft');

        darthVaderGroup.on('dragstart', function () {
            this.moveToTop();
        });
        // yoda
        var yodaImg = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 93,
            height: 104,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 4,
            name: 'rect'
        });

        yodaGroup.add(yodaImg);
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 93, 0, 'topRight');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 93, 104, 'bottomRight');
        addAnchor(yodaGroup, 0, 104, 'bottomLeft');

        yodaGroup.on('dragstart', function () {
            this.moveToTop();
        });

        var rect3 = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 93,
            height: 104,
            fill: 'blue',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 4,
            name: 'rect'
        });

        Group3.add(rect3);
        addAnchor(Group3, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
        addAnchor(Group3, 93, 0, 'topRight');
        addAnchor(Group3, 93, 104, 'bottomRight');
        addAnchor(Group3, 0, 104, 'bottomLeft');

        Group3.on('dragstart', function () {
            this.moveToTop();
        });

        stage.draw();

        //Deleting selected shape 
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            if (layer !== null && e.keyCode == 46) {  //Delete Key = 46
                SelectedShape.remove();
                layer.batchDraw();
            }
        });

        //Selecting on mousedown
        layer.on('mousedown', function (evt) {
            SelectedShape = evt.targetNode.getParent();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Some sample code please!

Comment: @markE Here u go with sample code. BTW error is different in sample code, but still related to null reference.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
//Selecting on mousedown
    layer.on('mousedown', function (evt) {
        SelectedShape = evt.targetNode.getParent();
    });
```

You can just delete that block of code...

And add an event listener to each shape instead:

```
 yodaGroup.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {SelectedShape = this;});
```

Then it will work.